# Angular Firefox (class constructors must be invoked with |new|)

Tags: angularjs

I get the following error when running my application in Firefox, the same does **not** happen in Edge,or Chrome:

> TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with |new| Stack-Trace:

```
h/<.invoke@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:44:169
wf/this.$get</</<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:94:33
n@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:69:42
ga/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:80:323
h/<@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:134:467
Mf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:145:417
Mf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:149:111
l@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:102:87
wg/</A.onload@http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:107:489
```

Additional Context: I am new to Angular, and I don't have much of an idea where to start to fix or debug this.

My main.js looks like this:

```
angular.module('appointmentApp')
  .component('main', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main.html',
    controller: MainController
  });
```

**Question:**
Can someone advise me on how to go about debugging and resolving this browser specific issue?

**Edit: Some More Code**

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

class MainController {

 constructor($http,$mdMedia,$mdDialog) {
    this.message = 'Hello';
    this.$http=$http;
    this.appointment = [];
    this.slots = [];
    this.$mdMedia = $mdMedia;
    this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    //...
    }

  
  save(appointment){
    //...
    });
        
  }
  
  $onInit(){
    var vm = this;
    this.$http.get('/api/data').then(response=>{
        this.data=response.data;
        this.dates = this.allot(this.slots,this.days,this.appointments);
    });
  }

  

allot(slots, days, appointments){
 //...
}


  showAdvanced(slot) {
      var vm = this;
    var useFullScreen = (this.$mdMedia('sm') || this.$mdMedia('xs'))  && this.customFullscreen;
    this.$mdDialog.show({
      controller: function($scope,$mdDialog,slot){
          $scope.customer = {};
          $scope.customer.slot = slot;
        $scope.answer = function(answer){
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/customer.html',
      locals : {
          slot : slot
      },
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
      fullscreen: useFullScreen
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
        answer.date = answer.slot.date;
        vm.save(answer);
    });
    
  }
  
  getColor($index) {
    var _d = ($index + 1) % 11;
    var bg = '';

    switch(_d) {
      case 1:       bg = 'green';       break;
      case 2:       bg = 'darkBlue';    break;
      default:      bg = 'yellow';      break;
    }

    return bg;
  }
 

}

angular.module('appointmentApp')
  .component('main', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main.html',
    controller: MainController
  });

})();
```

Comment: Could you share some code from your MainController please?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Firefox regarding native ES6 class support in combination with Angular. This was fixed in FF version 55.

See the bug report here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1216630

And the corresponding AngularJS issue blog here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14240#issuecomment-197418167

Alternatively you can include a ES6->ES5 transpilation step in your build (ex. with Babel), as native ES6 support could be risky on older browser versions.